# What is the cofactor of an element that is zero in a matrix?

Tags: matrices

Does the cofactor of an element in a matrix that is zero always equal to zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of a matrix at entry $(i,j)$ does not change the [cofactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) $C_{i,j}$, which is defined as $(-1)^{i+j}M_{i,j}$, where $M_{i,j}$ is the determinant of the matrix obtained by deleting the $i^\text{th}$ row and $j^\text{th}$ column.  Note that in particular these deletions delete the $(i,j)^\text{th}$ entry, so they do not affect either $(-1)^{i+j}$ (which depends only on the parity of $i,j$) nor $M_{i,j}$.